# How to sort NSTableView with NSArrayController programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, tableview, nsarraycontroller

I have a NSTableView with just one column but different values in subviews. The tableView is populated by NSArrayController which is bound to a CoreData entity.
I was wondering how to sort the tableView by custom buttons.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet var arrayController: NSArrayController!

   @IBAction func sortByName(_ sender: Any) {

       arrayController.sort... ?
   }

   @IBAction func sortByAge(_ sender: Any) {

       arrayController.sort... ?

   }

}
```

I know how to make NSArrayController to sort the columns by clicking on the row header. But since I have only one column but different values, I´m trying to find a way to sort by custom buttons.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the sort descriptors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `sortDescriptors` property of the array controller and call  `arrayController.rearrangeObjects()`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arrayController: NSArrayController!

    @IBAction func sortByName(_ sender: Any) {
        sortArrayController(by: "name")
    }

    @IBAction func sortByAge(_ sender: Any) {
        sortArrayController(by: "age")
    }

    func sortArrayController(by key : String) {
        arrayController.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: true)]
        arrayController.rearrangeObjects()
    }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't have to call `rearrangeObjects`, setting `sortDescriptors` will do that.